Reading special characters like (+) is not working with useSearchParams() get method
Reading special characters like + is not working with useSearchParams get() in next/navigation
const url = http://localhost:3000/cards?user=abc+desc@gmail.com
const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const singleParam = searchParams.get("user")

return as abc desc@gmail.com`
this method returns query value without + sign.

Because + in a URL query string does not mean +, but is the encoding for a space character. If you want to transport an actual + character via URL, then you need to properly URL-encode it.

+ is a special character used to encode a space in URLs (a remnant form the days of indexed searching, which nowadays is all but deprecated). You need to encode the query string before using it:
const url = http://localhost:3000/cards?user=abc%2Bdesc@gmail.com
// + is encoded to %2B

